# Delimited columns on console tabular prints

Tags: scripting, console, delimiter

I have a tabular text printed to the console, like below (output of the `nmcli dev wifi` command):

```
*  SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*  CAYO              Infra  5     54 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
   Jean              Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
   Jackson           Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2      
   capitao           Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
   Fernanda          Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
   Morais-Room       Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
   Rinaldi           Infra  3     54 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA2      
   Eni               Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
   Doidinho          Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
   Casa das Primas   Infra  8     54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2      
   Marcos Vinicius   Infra  3     54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
   MONICA            Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2      
   gabriela          Infra  3     54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
   Rinaldi           Infra  3     54 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
   LUAN              Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2      
   Vanessa           Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2      
   2 M Constru       Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2
```

I need to separate each column (and yours respective rows) by some char delimiter (like commas, for example).

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like the `--terse` option to nmcli will already do what you want, using `:` as the field separator. Or is the problem that you're not in control of running the command and are stuck with the output as-is?

Comment: Excellent, Benjamin !! I read about the --terse, at https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html, but initially had not understood how it should be used. Now I was able to use the tab with --t and select the columns with --f.

Thank you very much!!!